# Error in mysql query for getting rank from total mark

Tags: mysql

I want to get rank based on total mark in a student table.

```
SET @PreviousRecord = NULL;
SET @Rank = 0;
SELECT studentid,total,result CASE
    WHEN @PreviousRecord = total 
        THEN @Rank
    WHEN @PreviousRecord := total 
        THEN @Rank := @Rank + 1
    END AS ranks
FROM studentdetails

ORDER BY total;
```

Its not working got error as

> 20 errors were found during analysis.
>     Unrecognized keyword. (near "CASE" at position 30)
>   Unrecognized keyword. (near "WHEN" at position 37)
>   Unexpected token. (near "@PreviousRecord" at position 42)
>   Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 58)
>   Unexpected token. (near "total" at position 60)
>   Unrecognized keyword. (near "THEN" at position 80)
>   Unexpected token. (near "@Rank" at position 85)
>   Unrecognized keyword. (near "WHEN" at position 93)
>   Unexpected token. (near "@PreviousRecord" at position 98)
>   Unexpected token. (near ":=" at position 114)
>   Unexpected token. (near "total" at position 117)
>   Unrecognized keyword. (near "THEN" at position 137)
>   Unexpected token. (near "@Rank" at position 142)
>   Unexpected token. (near ":=" at position 148)
>   Unexpected token. (near "@Rank" at position 151)
>   Unexpected token. (near "+" at po

My table structure is

[image]

Comment: provide your full query.

Comment: Thats all my query

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error here: `result CASE` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @Rank = 0;
SELECT @Rank := @Rank+1,Z.studentid,Z.total
FROM
(
SELECT studentid,total
FROM studentdetails order by total
)Z
```

Try above query.

Comment: can you please tell what `Z` means in your query

Comment: i had just given alias to subquery.

Comment: Did it.. Thank you

Comment: Ur Always Welcom